# Unexpected grid behavior in tkinter - elements aligned incorrectly

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a simple UI with Tkinter and can't seem to find a mistake.

Here is the outcome:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.configure(padx=20, pady=20)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window)
canvas.configure(width=200, height=200)
image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

website_label = tkinter.Label(text="Website:")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

website_input = tkinter.Entry(width=35)
website_input.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)

email_username_label = tkinter.Label(text="Email/Username:")
email_username_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

email_username_input = tkinter.Entry(width=35)
email_username_input.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

password_label = tkinter.Label(text="Password:")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

password_input = tkinter.Entry(width=21)
password_input.grid(row=3, column=1)

generate_password_button = tkinter.Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_password_button.config(width=14)
generate_password_button.grid(row=3, column=2)

add_button = tkinter.Button(text="Add", width=21)
add_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

window.mainloop()
```

I expected my inputs and buttons to be correctly aligned, i.e. password input to go under upper inputs and generate password button to go right next, fitted to the end of upper inputs.

I also expected Add button to start in the beginning of the upper inputs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when using `grid` the widgets will be centered in the row and column. That is what is happening here.

The simplest solution is to add the `sticky` attribute to each widget. That can be used to get the sides of a widget to "stick" to the sides of the row or column.

For example, add `sticky="ew"` in the following statements (where "ew" stands for "east, west"):

```
website_input.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
email_username_input.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
password_input.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="ew")
```

I personally think it's a best practice to always explicitly state the `sticky` values for every widget.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to try to establish some kind of canonical about how to use `.grid` properly. But I'm not qualified to phrase the question for it.

Comment: Thank you, Bryan, this worked like charm. Don't know why the course I'm taking never mentined it.